# Slim Framework Twig Templating using MD5 as required password hash/encryption

Tags: php, encryption, hash, md5, slim

I am trying to code an application around an existing database. It already has several hundred users and data involving those users. So trying to change over the database that is used by a different program(game) from md5 to password_bcrypt or the like is not possible. This application is supposed to be a user's panel to allow for profile info and display user's character information. what I have atm is using PASSWORD_BCRYPT. I can get it to register the user with the md5 hash, however, my biggest issue is coding a password check. Here is the current code using PASSWORD_BCRYPT:

```
    public function password($password)
{
    return password_hash(
        $password, 
        $this->config->get('app.hash.algo'), 
        ['cost' => $this->config->get('app.hash.cost')]
    );
}

public function passwordCheck($password, $hash)
{
    return password_verify($password, $hash);
}
```

Again I know how to write out the code to let the user register with an md5 hash, but when they login it fails. Here is the call to the passwordCheck function:

```
    if ($v->passes()) {
    $user = $app->user
    ->where('username', $identifier)
    ->first();


    if ($user && $app->hash->passwordCheck($password, $user->password)) {

        $_SESSION[$app->config->get('auth.session')] = $user->id;

        $app->flash('global', 'You are now signed in!');
    }  else {

        $app->flash('global', 'Could not log you in!');

    }

    $app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('login'));
}
```

any and all suggestions welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MD5 is deprecated as a password hash. Use SHA-256 or better.

Comment: if you had read you would not have said that. This database is connected to a game software I don't have the source for. So no i can't use a different hash. I know MD5 is very rarely used now days but  I can't change it if I don't have the original source. So I have to make what I can for a web panel with what is available hence MD5.

Comment: Actually, you can - and should - upgrade the hashing over time by rehashing passwords when users login. Yes, it will take time, but it's necessary if you want to keep your database secure.

Comment: I can't! it is a game system that is closed sourced. The original database system is/was Oracle Berkeley DB. It is hard coded. I literally can't change the encryption/hash. They log into a game that was made back in 2006-2008. So please stop telling me to upgrade when I can't. It uses a this type of code to hash the passwords : `"0x" . md5($password.$extra);` or `base64_encode(md5($password.$extra);`

Comment: As I understood your question, the database is pre-existing, but I thought that you implied that the original application was no longer in use. Apparently, I misunderstood. If you can't change the existing application's source, then yes, you may be stuck. Please note, however, that the tone of your comments (especially phrases like "if you had read" and "please stop telling me") may be taken as rude. You will find SO a very friendly and helpful community, but only if you respond to attempts to help a little more courteously.

Comment: As for your question, have you determined exactly how the original application does its hashing? From your comment, it sounds like it does a single round of `base64_encode(md5($password.$extra))`. If that is the case, then you can't use `password_hash` - it performs multiple rounds of hashing and salting, so you will not get the same result.

Comment: i apologize if it came off as rude. but my question was how do i write the code to use the above hash to allow for user login. not if i can change it. I can get the system register them. but when you try to login it fails.

Comment: I have an idea for a hack that would let you implement PASSWORD_BCRYPT without changing the database schema.  Use their current MD5 hash as a pointer to a text file that contains a BCRYPT'd password (assuming you have the ability to write text files to a non-public directory).

Comment: I might be able to if the owner set's up the right permissions. but i was hoping to just in the code have it compare the login password hash to the stored one and if the check is successful tell the verify script it is okay and set the session.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that because I need to use a different hash, I can't use PASSWORD_HASH or the follow up function password_verify since the password_verify is checking apparently for the password_hash function. I'm not totally sure. But the following code is what works:

```
    public function password($encrypt)
{
    $encrypt = $salt . md5($encrypt);

    return $encrypt;
}

public function passwordCheck($password, $hash)
{
    return (strcmp($password, $hash) == 0);
 }
```

the salt is a custom salt that I will keep to myself. I've tested this with my current app I am building and it is working like I want it to. The user can register and log in. Thanks for the help, but sadly the answer above came from else where. I know this isn't as secure as it should be but again it is a must since I am forced to use a pre-existing database that is still in use.